someone wants to send me money to do a painting of me,i get a cut of the money
There is a woman approached me on fb saying she likes my profile picture and wants to do a mural of me. she said her client is gonna fund her 2500. i get 500 for letting them paint a picture of me. she told me that the clients account manager will be texting me. her client says she is fine to send me a check for mobile deposit to my email address for easier access because i also need part of funds to get the art supplies to complete the painting and asking for my full name and email address where the check sent to

Yes, a scam. If someone wants to pay you for something, there's no need for this extra nonsense. In this scam, you deposit the check, you give them the 'extra' money in an irreversible way, then the deposit is reversed and you are out $2k+fees.

This question is similar to: Scam? Checks via Email. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Another potential duplicate: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/162781/linkedin-job-post-product-tester-recieved-a-email-check-pdf-to-deposit-so-i-ca

And obviously, when some random person wants to send you money for no good reason, it is a scam.

Even closer duplicate: Am I being scammed if someone asks for my full name and email address?. ("An artist on Instagram asked me if they could do a painting of me...")

See also https://www.reddit.com/r/Scams/comments/198vqe4/muse_scam/

This question is similar to: Is it a scam if someone asks for my full name, email, and bank name?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I also add the scam of sending a forged image of a check, which the reference to electronic deposit seems to suggest is what the scammer has in mind.

i also need part of funds to get the art supplies to complete the painting The artist doesn't already have art supplies? What are they asking you to buy, exactly? Is there a specific reason that they can't buy whatever supplies they need themselves? How do you even know what supplies they need? That's like a surgeon asking them to buy tools for them before the surgery.

This is a scam. You will get a check for $2,500. Your bank will deposit that check and you will see the balance in your account. Then you will send the money on to the "artist".
Then in a few weeks, the check will be revealed to be fake. You will be on the hook to pay back the bank the $2,500 and the money you sent to the "artist" will be long gone and unrecoverable.
Classic cash back scam.
